# Criteria For Calling Two Methods Overloaded Methods?

Tags: c#, overloading

I've seen in the C# specifications rules for which overloaded method gets used in a call, but I can't seem to find anything on what criteria needs to be satisfied for a method to actually be an overloaded method.

Here is my shot at it. Please let me know if you see any problems with it:

This does not take access modifiers or generics into consideration (I'm still a noob working my way through a C# book)

Consider two methods

- Make sure both methods have correct formal parameter lists
- Treat optional parameters as mandatory parameters
- Treat params like one mandatory parameter whose type is the type of the params array
- We have two lists of mandatory parameters
- (P1, P2, P3, P4) and (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
- P1 and Q1, P2 and Q2, … are parameter pairs
- To be overloaded methods, the two must have the same name but different parameter list

One of these must be false

- Same number of parameters
- Each parameter pair must have same type
- Each parameter pair must both have a parameter-modifier or both not have a parameter modifier.

Example:  method(ref int a) and method(out int a) are not overloaded methods

- Both 1 parameter
- Both are int
- Both have a parameter modifier

Comment: Method overloading is a language-agnostic concept. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @RJLohan The exact rules for method overloading are not language-agnostic.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question isn't clear. Please bear with me, this is my first post on stackoverflow. What I want to know is once two methods have correct formal parameter lists, what has to be different between the two methods for them to be overloaded methods and not create an error because they are seen by the compiler as an attempt to create the same method twice

Comment: For instance Method(ref int a) and Method(out int a) are seen as the same method and give an error. Also I've read a few times that params doesn't matter for distinguishing methods from each other, but I have not seen an error for Method(int a) and Method(int a, params int[] b) or an error for Method() and Method(params int[] a)

Comment: Well, not an error but a warning...

Comment: @svick Of course not, I understand that. I just don't understand the purpose of a question that is effectively 'C# Method overloading, discuss.'

Answer (score 2):

Normally "method overloading" refers to methods with the same name (including +/- operators) but with different arguments.

The term "overloaded" is not strictly defined to mean anything specific in C# language (unlike "method signature"). The closes place to a definition is probably section "3.6 Signatures and overloading" of C# 4.0 specification:

> Signatures are the enabling mechanism for **overloading** of members in classes, structs, and interfaces:
>
> - Overloading of methods permits a class, struct, or interface to declare multiple methods with the same name, provided their signatures are unique within that class, struct, or interface.
> - Overloading of instance constructors permits a class or struct to declare multiple instance constructors, provided their signatures are unique within that class or struct.
> - Overloading of indexers permits a class, struct, or interface to declare multiple indexers, provided their signatures are unique within that class, struct, or interface.
> - Overloading of operators permits a class or struct to declare multiple operators with the same name, provided their signatures are unique within that class or struct.

Comment: All the info is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx (except for the unclear point that may lead you to believe out/ref parameters are considered to be distinct when they are not - at least by the VS2010 compiler)

Comment: Thanks Alexei for your reply! I've read that part of the specification but, correct me if I'm wrong, params is not part of the signature of a function. Also I have seen that params does have an impact on distinguishing overloaded methods from each other. Therefore there seem to be other things at play besides the signature when determining if two functions are seen by the compiler as the same thing or legitimate overloaded methods

Comment: @RJLohan I've read that link. See my comment above this to Alexei

Comment: Sorry - I can't answer this. I've never had reasons to dig into precise cases when signature of methods cause warnings/errors because of collision on parameters. If you find it in real coding most likely your class is hard to use and would benefit from simplification. Since out/ref arguments are rare (and not generally recommended) and params are even less common I would simply skim this section till you really need to either implement C# specification or find real life usage.